# Trying to install Leviton smart switches replacing two older switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Am I installing this correctly?

I'm trying to install two new Leviton smart switches. Had two neutrals tied off, so pig tailed them. Does first switch need be replaced as well? It's a Lutron dimmer.  Needless to say, the switches do not work.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what these switches control. Also, do you have a picture of how this was wired before you started? When you say "two neutrals tied off" I presume you mean there were two neutrals tied to each other that didn't appear to go anywhere in the box itself. Also, please confirm with a HOT voltage tester or a meter you only have ONE HOT circuit in this box and that it is cotrolled by ONE circuit breaker.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: Yes, the neutrals were capped off in the back of the box. The two switches I removed were wired just like the two new levitron switches. The only difference is I added the two pig tails for the neutrals.  The switches 2 thru 5 are chained tigether by the red wire. Switch 5 works fine. Its connected to a single closet light. Switches 3 and 4, the new levitrons, are connected to outside garage lights.  One switch will- I hope - operate to fixtures next to the garage door, and the other will operate three recessed lights.

Comment: Oh, and these four switches, two thru five, are on the same circuit. Switch one is on a different circuit and is not connected to 2 thru 5.

Comment: Be careful. Multiple circuits in a workbox are -- BUT you must keep the circuits SEPARATE, which is not the case here. Other folks may be more encouraging, but I would call a professional. There's just too much opportunity to do something that appears to work but isn't safe (mixed neutrals, polarity issues etc) and I'm talking about the previous owner's handiwork, not yours.

Comment: Where are you in the world? And when you answered my question on neutral, you didn't actually tell us what we needed to know. Was there TWO neutral wires under ONE cap, tied together? Also, no, your wiring doesnt look correct as it appears you have one switch ganged to another in series, and a neutral on a feeder line... so we're going to really need to know how it was wired before you touched it because I think you may have wired the LOAD/FEEDER/LINE wrong where the dumb switches chained one or more circuits. Please post 1 photo of one of the old switches or call an electrician.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input. I got this working. Started the sequence from right to left. The white neutrals were two wires capped off under one cap. The pigtailing worked for the neutrals to the new switches. What I had wrong was switch two was chained to switch three with a red. I ran that, which should have been hot, to the reds that are pigtailed together.  Then I relooked at the wiring diagram and was able to get the switch wires adjusted.  Bottom line, working well.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!